# How can I get the initial value of a comboBox?

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4.1

I need get the initial value of a comboBox to charge a tooltip on my application, i got this method but this not charge nothing

```
var raw = ComboRegisted.combo.getRawValue();
Ext.QuickTips.register({ target: ComboRegisted.combo.getEl(), text: COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaFechaAprobacion") + raw.fechaAprobacion + 
"<br/>" + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaCO") + raw.normaCO + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaUnidad1") +
"<br/>" + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaHC") + raw.normaHC + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaUnidad1") + 
"<br/>" + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaNox") + raw.normaNox + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaUnidad1") +  
"<br/>" + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaPM") + raw.normaPM + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaUnidad1") +  
"<br/>" + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaHumo") + raw.normaHumo + COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME, "tooltipNormativaUnidad2" )});

this.comboMap.register(ComboRegisted.ID, ComboRegisted.meta, ComboRegisted.combo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem i get the answer now.

I do this:

```
var recordSelected = ComboRegisted.combo.store.getAt(ComboRegisted.combo.getValue());
var raw = recordSelected.raw;
```

and this go good.